# How to use sass absolute paths in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, sass

In `nextjs`, in the file `tsconfig.json`, run the following command
`"baseUrl": "src",` to change the absolute path.
So I can navigate to the path from `src/` when importing from a component.

However, when I browse the file via `@use` inside the `sass` file, the absolute path I set above is not set and I can browse from the root directory. How can I fix this?